# Inno Setup - Prompt to user to insert the next setup disk/CD/DVD

Tags: installation, inno-setup, cd, dvd

I am currently working on a setup package for a rather large program (over 5Gb) that I have to distribute via CDs or DVDs. My problem is that I never had to do such a thing and I don't know how to do so. I know that I have to enable `DiskSpanning` to allow the package to be divided in severals BINs and use `DiskSliceSize` to ensure that the slices can be burnt on CDs/DVDs. But how do I make the package prompt the user to insert the next CD?

Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup does it for you automatically, when there are multiple slices. There's nothing you need to do explicitly.

[image: Setup Needs the Next Disk]