# Best Disk Spanning settings in Inno Setup Compiler

Tags: inno-setup

What is the perfect settings for

[image]

That can fit to a CD and DVD .

**or** is it possible to split them in equal sizes like for

- setup-1.bin = 1 gb
- setup-2.bin = 1 gb
- setup-x.bin = [remaining size]

and can't have errors when some .bin parts are missing [*not in same directory*] instead it will prompt to find the next .bin part.

Like WinRAR split files/ x parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`DiskSliceSize` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_diskslicesize):

```
[Setup]
DiskSliceSize=1073741824
```

The prompt comes automatically with that:
[Inno Setup - Prompt to user to insert the next setup disk/CD/DVD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35712776/850848)

Comment: But SolidCompression=no if you put it in dvd or cd? SolidCompression=yes if it's in the same folder/location?

Comment: Yes solid compression will do more harm than good with large spanned installations. As documented.